# Pandas convert csv data to floats

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read data from csv and compute new values. Pandas interprets data as strings, hence, I cannot do math on values. attempt to convert values to floats fails as well. What is the correct way to convert string `df` to `floats`?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', names=['Open','High','Low','Close'])

#TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['High']-df['Low'])/df['Close']

#ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Low'
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['High'].astype(float)-df['Low'].astype(float))/df['Close'].astype(float)
print(df.head())

# head.csv
# Open,High,Low,Close
# 100.1,110.1,90.1,101.1
# 100.2,110.2,90.2,101.2
# 100.3,110.3,90.3,101.3
# 100.4,110.4,90.4,101.4
```

Comment: You probably have some rows that aren't numeric, or at least cant be safely interpreted as a number?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the header. Should have skipped it like this:

`df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', names=['Open','High','Low','Close'], skiprows=[0])`